# When i am using UdpClient.Connect and UdpClient.Send it gives No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?

Tags: c#, .net, udp, udpclient

I am using a punchin machine and fetching its data using **UdpClient** and it gives us perfectely but now i want to send flag back to that machine which one have sent us the datagrams.I am getting the IPAddress of sender machine in variable **ipAddress** and port number in **portNo** variable.But when i tried to use UdpClient.Connect or Udpclient.Send to send data to a specific ip then it gives **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**  How can i do it?

```
UdpClient udpServer = new UdpClient(7005);
var receivedResults = await udpServer.ReceiveAsync();
Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Is anybody there");
try
{
var ipAddress = Convert.ToString(receivedResults.RemoteEndPoint.Address);
var portNo = receivedResults.RemoteEndPoint.Port;
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), portNo);
//udpServer.Connect(endpoint);
udpServer.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, endpoint);
}
```

Comment: This type of error is usually down to a firewall, or nothing listening on that port on the target machine. Is the client running on the same machine as the server? Or are they traversing a network/the internet where firewalls could be in the way? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it for more information.

Comment: the client  machine is locally connected with my server.Its a punch in machine that gives us the punched in records and now i want to send flag back to that machine

Comment: OK. Please take a look at the solution in this article, it seems to be what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038943/simple-udp-example-to-send-and-receive-data-from-same-socket