# How does having a central server circumvent things like NAT

Tags: python, networking, nat

I'm trying to develop a small multiplayer game and I've been reading a lot about how NAT makes P2P impossible.
On the other hand I've read a lot of server code which looks something like:

[https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038943/simple-udp-example-to-send-and-receive-data-from-same-socket)

```
def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
    message = data.decode()
    print('Received %r from %s' % (message, addr))
    print('Send %r to %s' % (message, addr))
    self.transport.sendto(data, addr)
```

In the above code the server talks to the client using only plain IP address.
Similarly [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038943/simple-udp-example-to-send-and-receive-data-from-same-socket)

So what am I missing here - is there another way to write UDP send calls or does having them sit on a server auto-magically solves NAT?

Answer (score 0):

The crucial part is this one: `client.Connect(ep);`. The client is the one opening the connection to the server. If a connection is established, the client's router knows where to route incoming packets over the public port.

Having just a server does not circumvent the NAT problem. The same issues as with P2P would exists.